# Faster way than -forwardInvocation: to perform messages on a specific thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, sqlite

To improve responsiveness, some synchronous methods that used FMDB to execute SQLite queries on the main thread were rewritten to be asynchronous, and run in the background via `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`.  SQLite not being thread-safe, however, each of these methods would ultimately call `-[FMDatabase open]`, decreasing overall performance.

So, I wrote a proxy for the FMDB classes, which overrode `-forwardInvocation:` to perform `-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]` on one specific thread, via `-performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.  This solved the problem of too many calls to `-[FMDatabase open]`, but `-forwardInvocation:` itself is rather expensive.

Is there a good way to solve this performance issue without rewriting all of the code that calls FMDB methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've found the problem: don't call `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`! There's no guarantee what it'll do, but it probably won't do the right thing.

If what you want is a single "database thread" for background ops, then there are several options:

- Create a new database thread and run loop and use `-performSelector:onThread:...` instead.
- Create an NSOperationQueue with maxConcurrentOperationCount=1 and use NSOperation (NSInvocationOperation, perhaps?), or a serial dispatch queue. *This isn't quite right:* the operations/blocks are not guaranteed to be executed on the same thread, which might break sqlite (IIRC you can only move a DB handle between threads after freeing all statements)
- Use NSOperationQueue, but save a thread-local reference to the database in `[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary]`. This is a bit messy, since you have little control over when the database disappears. It also might violate the NSOperation contract (you're supposed to return the thread to its original state when the operation finishes).

Comment: I am already using `-performSelector:onThread:...` with a database run loop thread. That's what I call in `-forwardInvocation:`. I'm using `-forwardInvocation:` to avoid rewriting the existing main thread and background thread code. It works, but the forwarding adds a fair amount of overhead.

Comment: I mean call `-performSelector:onThread:...` instead of `-performSelectorInBackground:`, and let the main thread use its own DB handle. Do you mean you want both the background thread(s) and the main thread to share a DB handle? That's potentially a recipe for disaster. SQLite supports concurrent access of the same DB from multiple threads/processes with a small amount of overhead (cached data is invalidated after a write).

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think you're right; I should only consolidate the background threads with each other, not also the main thread.  Right now, the main thread and the `-performSelectorInBackground:` threads share a DB handle, but access is serialized via the database run loop thread.  I'm already using SQLITE_OPEN_SHAREDCACHE, but I don't think I could take advantage of SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX without rewriting significant parts of FMDB that assume single-threaded access.

Comment: FMDB assumes that other processes don't touch the DB? Ouch. Another option is to do *processing* in a background thread and return results to the main thread for writing to sqlite. Unless you're writing silly amounts of data, it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Yeah, see `-[FMDatabase compainAboutInUse]`, for example.  Unfortunately, the expensive thing is the sheer number of queries, not time spent processing the results.

Comment: I think that's only specific to a FMDatabase object, not the database itself. Unless FMDatabase does additional caching of database rows, you should be fine.

Comment: It is per-`FMDatabase`, but the existing code uses FMDB, not SQLite directly, so the database handle is abstracted away.  `FMDatabase`'s initializer is `-initWithPath:`, which was a source of performance issues.  Each `-performInBackground:` method would allocate its own `FMDatabase`, which would ultimately `open()` the database file, and create a new handle.